# How to set css dynamically in v-for?

Tags: css, vue.js, v-for

After consulting the VUE official website and many other places still can not find a better solution, I hope to get help, thanks for all

```html
            <div class="tag-item" :ref="`tagItem_${index}`">
              <el-tooltip effect="dark" :content="tag.name" placement="top">
                <el-link :underline="false" class="title" @click="getPostByTag(tag)">
                  <el-image :src="tag.img" style="height: 32px; z-index: 99; width: 32px" lazy />
                  <span class="content" :id="`content_${index}`" :class="judgeScroll(index)">{{
                    tag.name
                  }}</span>
                </el-link>
              </el-tooltip>
            </div>
```

```js
const tagItem_0 = ref()

const judgeScroll = (index) => {
  nextTick(() => {
    // console.log(tagItem_0.value[0].clientWidth)
    let contentWidth = document.getElementById(`content_${index}`).clientWidth
    // console.log(contentWidth)
    if (+contentWidth > +tagItem_0.value[0].clientWidth) {
      // console.log('==================')
      document.getElementById(`content_${index}`).classList.add('scroll')
      return 'scroll'
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.tag-list {
  margin: 10px;
  min-height: 32px;
  min-width: 10%;

  .tag-item {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1%;
    max-width: 100%;

    .title {
      color: #262626;
      display: block;
      line-height: 20px;
      font-size: 13px;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      word-wrap: normal;
      max-width: inherit;
      align-items: center;

      .content {
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .scroll {
        animation: scrollText 10s linear infinite;
        @keyframes scrollText {
          0% {
            transform: translateX(30%);
          }
          100% {
            transform: translateX(-100%);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my imagination, when the text in span is too long, set CSS to slide it left and right. If I can successfully set the scroll style, this is successful.

If `scroll` is injected successfully, it should run like this. If the text is short, it will not be injected into `scroll`
[scroll example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJucn.gif)

I want to add a 'scroll' style to all `<span>` that is width than the parent node. When I try to write it below, the method executes the final log, but not the return 'scroll' style as expected, until I add the sentence `classList.add`.

I have two questions now.
The first is that if I don't add `nextTick,tagItem.value` `[0]`, null will appear, and the second is why there is no return 'scroll'.

In addition, when I use the above as a component, and two components appear at the same page, the style will be added to the first component at the same time. Is there a solution to this situation?
Finally, thank you for reading the post. Any suggestions and criticisms are also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.The judgeScroll function will run at 'beforCreate lifecycle' in the first time,and this time the dom is not yet created,so the tagItem_0.value[0] is null
2. There is no return value in judgeScroll ,your  return is in a callback of nextTick,
3. Vue does not suggest use document Object,if you used, maybe your code needs to optimize
4. How about the style 'overflow: auto'

supplement:
delete the judgeScroll function, change the style like this : .content {white-space: nowrap; overflow: auto;display: inline-block;width: calc(100% - 32px );}
And if possible  show your code on codepen so I can run it

Comment: Thank you for your answer. According to your answer, how should I optimize my code? I don't know if I can ask you to provide some help. I also understand that document is not recommended in vue, but I feel that there is seem no more convenient way. On the fourth point, I will add more code. @moon

Comment: Thanks again for your patience and help. I've tried the CSS you suggested, but it didn't work very well on my project. I also put my code in codepen, but I've never tried codepen before, the code is not running very well, if you do not mind, you can see my code through this [link](https://codepen.io/guapi_L/pen/rNPrqwg) @moon

Comment: [Is this what you want](https://codepen.io/copyingMachine/pen/yLZqGxv)

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty close, but I was hoping that when `name` gets too long, it would dynamically inject the `scroll` style so that it would scroll up automatically, so. `content's overflow` should be set to hidden. I'm not sure why `scroll` style doesn't work in codepen. I'll add a [gif example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJucn.gif) to the question to show how `scroll` works

Comment: Oh,Isee,[check it again](https://codepen.io/copyingMachine/pen/yLZqGxv)

Comment: Wow, you have provided the code is very much in line with my ideas, the remaining details I believe I can solve, finally thanks again for your patience to help